# how to make rewriterule add anchors to wordpress url inestead of "/"?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, anchor

I'm a .htaccess nOOb, but I think this is the best way to do it. 
I need to make wordpress change the '/' into '#' in the url. The structure goes like: 
http://thewebsite/pageid/sub_pageid and the desired effect would be http://thewebsite/pagid#sub_pageid . I've tried few rules I found on-line, but each one of them have failed. I believe its because I have those rules applied to it. There is only one page I have subpages for and it's the only one that needs rewriting. After the redirect I want jquery to scroll down to the anchor.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /thewebsite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /thewebsite/index.php 
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I've tried RewriteRule ^page/ page# [NE] but I've failed. I've tried many others, but no effect. Hope someone had this problem before and just knows, or can explain why I fail. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just trying to rewrite it for a single page, try:

```
RewriteRule [page\_id]\/(.*) /page_id#$1 [NE,R=301]
```

That should be all you need for a specific page id or string. NE means 'noescape,' allowing you to rewrite the hash (#) symbol.

For any page id:

```
RewriteRule ([0-9]+)\/(.*) /$2#$1 [NE,R=301]
```

Comment: unfortunately: nothing happened. Even if I try to change the page_id nothing happens. it's like it doesn't recognize the page_id. I'm running it on localhost - have no idea if it changes anything. I might try to test it on the original server, but I don't think it helps. I'm suspecting that some other rules I'm using are causing this to fail. more ideas ?

Comment: Are your other rules working? Perhaps AllowOverride is not set to All in your Directory configuration?

Comment: Yes, the other Rules work and if I do something wrong intentionally ig gives me errors, so Im'm positive the .htaccess works. I even tried RewriteRule pageid asdasda [NE,R=301]
and it gave me error with asdasda in the URL.

Comment: I believe 
    RewriteRule . /thewebsite/index.php [L] and
    RewriteRule [pageid]\/(.*) pageid#$1 [NE,R=301]

those 2 rules somehow interfere

Answer (score 0):

Try this following code if not necessary skip the rewrite contidion download/.php ,make sure that you have to put a 404 file in your domain folder

```
 RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule (.*) index.php
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} .*\.php|/$
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !download\.php
    RewriteRule !/ index.php

    ErrorDocument 401 /401.html
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: I don't see any '#' sign and I want to do anchors ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, 
Since I'm a .htaccess-lame I decided to use jQuery to solve my problem. I used .attr() to replace the original attribute 'href'. I've managed to change the links to subpages with:

```
$(function(){
        $('#menu_on_HOME a').each(function(i){
        var atitle = $(this).attr("href");
        var strRep = atitle;
            n = strRep.lastIndexOf('/'); //finds the last occurence of '/' to replace with '#'
                if (n >= 0 && n + strRep.length >= strRep.length) {
                    strRep = strRep.substring(0, n) + "#" + strRep.substring(n + 1, n + strRep.length); // this is where magic happens
                }
        $(this).attr("href", strRep); //here is where I replace the original attribute 'href'
        });
    });
```

The function above sends me to page#subpage where PAGE contains the content of all subpages and clicking on the menu_on_HOME link goes straight to subpage anchor. Moreover, on the actual PAGE i have internal links to subpages (the content can be editable via cms as a page) but I didn't need to go deeper into subpage but rather get the desired anchor, so I used [ScrollTo](http://flesler-plugins.googlecode.com/files/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js) :

```
 $(function(){
        $('menu_on_PAGE a').each(function(i){
        var atitle = $(this).attr("href");
        var strRep = atitle;
            n = strRep.lastIndexOf('/'); 
            var name;
                if (n >= 0 && n + strRep.length >= strRep.length) {
                    name = strRep.substring(n + 1, n + strRep.length);
                    strRep = strRep.substring(0, n) + "#" + name;
                $(this).click(function(event){
                    var scroller = '#content a[name=' + name + ' ]'; //point to the anchor
            $(window).scrollTo(scroller,{duration:1500});
            });
                }
        $(this).attr("href", strRep);

        });
    });
$(window)._scrollable();
```

I don't know how 'right' or 'wrong' the solution is, however it works for me flawlessly :)